# Organise a spa break over a weekend departing from West Sussex

Tags: uk, europe

I would like to organise a little weekend spa break for me and my girlfriend, we are based in West Sussex, UK.

We would like to get some sauna, some bubbly water and maybe some massage and relax.

I've spotted a few options (http://www.aquasana.co.uk/ being the most promising), and lots of hotels self called "spa"s, when they have just a pool. I'm finding it hard to find a nice place to suit our needs.

The Aquasana looks all right, but the prices are way over budget. So I'm looking for alternatives all over Europe (for example I heard that in Hungary they do great spas).

I'm finding it hard to organise this trip, so I'm looking for hints on how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
G

Comment: We can't really answer this on TSE as per  [our rules](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'm a great fan of the spas in the Taunus, but agree with @JoErNanO, we cannot act as travel agents.....